# Scrapy using python3 directory (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed scrapy with `sudo pip install scrapy`. Installed without errors, but it won't run.

```
scrapy --version
```

returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==0.24.6', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 521, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2632, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2312, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2318, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import _monkeypatches
ImportError: No module named '_monkeypatches'
```

Why is this looking in my python 3 directory?

Comment: Look at where your `scrapy` is located, and then check your $PYTHONPATH and $PATH. Might give you a direction.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used it to solve my problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question:

I looked in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`. Each had a folder for scrapy. I took the following steps to resolve:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall scrapy
sudo pip uninstall scrapy
sudo pip install scrapy
```

It now works as expected.

EDIT: Thanks again to boardrider for the tip which led me to this solution.

Comment: When _I_ post an answer which is based on others' suggestions, I *credit* them...

Comment: I had added a response to your comment above thanking you. Maybe you didn't see it. I'll edit the answer as well to add thanks.